# How to connect a flask container with a mysql container

Tags: docker, flask, dockerfile, containers, database-connection

I have already a mysql container named "mysqlDemoStorage" running, exposing port 3306 to 0.0.0.0:3306. I also have a flask app which provides a login page and table-displaying page. The flask app works quite well in host. The login page connects to "user" table in the mysql container and the table-displaying page connects to another table holding all the data to display.
The docker-compose file I used to create the mysql container is as follows:

```
version: '3'
services: 
    mysql:
        container_name: mysqlDemoStorage
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "demo"
        command: 
            --character-set-server=utf8
        ports: 
            - 3306:3306
        image: "docker.io/mysql:latest"
        restart: always
```

Now I want to dockerize the flask app so that I can still view the app from host. The mysql container detail is as followed:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
c48955b3589e        mysql:latest        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   13 days ago         Up 49 minutes       0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   mysqlDemoStorage
```

The dockerfile of the flask app I wrote is as follows:

```
FROM python:latest
WORKDIR /storage_flask
ADD . /storage_flask
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["python","run.py"]
```

The flask image can be successfuly built, but when I run the image, I fail to load the page. One point I think that causes the problem is the **init**.py file to initiate the flask app, which is as follows:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager

app = Flask(__name__)    

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'aafa4f8047ce31126011638be8530da6'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://root:demo@localhost:3306/storage'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
login_manager = LoginManager(app)
login_manager.login_view = "login"
login_manager.login_message_category = 'info'

from storage_flask import routes
```

I was thinking passing the IP of the mysql container to the flask container as the config string for DB connection. But I'm not sure how to do it.
Could someone help to solve the problem? Thank you

Comment: Use the service name: instead of demo@localhost, use demo@mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://root:demo@localhost:3306/storage'
```

to

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://root:demo@mysql:3306/storage'
```

You also need to make sure that both containers are connected to the same network, for that  you need to update your docker-compose file to be something like the below file

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  my_network_name:
    name: my_network_name
    external: false

services:
  mysql:
    container_name: mysqlDemoStorage
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "demo"
    command:
      --character-set-server=utf8
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    image: "docker.io/mysql:latest"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - my_network_name
```

second file

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  my_network_name:
    name: my_network_name
    external: true

services:
  python_app:
    container_name: pythonDemoStorage
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    image: "Myimage"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - my_network_name
```

Comment: I did the change, but it still doesn't work. I inspect the hosts file of the mysql container, it shows "172.19.0.2 c48955b3589e". I think I should change the hostname, but I don't how to do it from powershell.

Comment: no, you don't need to change that . are you running both applications from the same docker-compose file ? or you have different files ?

Comment: Sadly no, I run the mysql container from docker-compse file. The flask container I run it with its own dockerfile and try to add it to the network where mysql container locates. Should I redo it with one docker-compose file?

Comment: you can split it into multiple files, but you need to select the network for all files to be the same, I update the answer with an example

Comment: Thank you. Now I can run my container and login via local browser. I came into some error when adapting your answer and made some change to make it work. I used "version: '3.7'", because with 3, the error indicates that the "name" is unexpected. Thank you very much for your help.